Calculating/determining point on elevation surface closest to point underground using ArcGIS Pro
I wish to find the spot on the earth's surface that is closest to my underground point.
Which tools do I use to calculate this?
I am modeling in a Gobal Scene various layers, including one layer which contains 3D points ('Point ZM') that are at fixed elevations (all underground, always beneath the elevation surface). For one of these points, I wish to calculate the point/spot on the elevation surface ('WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D') that is closest.
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.2.

I have tried Near 3D, but the elevation surface (Ground>WorldElevation3D/Terrain3d) is not one of the features I can choose from to perform the calculation (and nor are other layers that I have in the scene, e.g., a 2D LiDAR DEM layer).

BTW, this not for professional purposes; it is for a personal hobby project I am working on.
